# How to save prefab modifictions made in Prefab Mode (prefab editing view, Unity 2018 +) using custom Editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a prefab with a MonoBehaviour script named `RoomInfo` on it. I'm using a custom Editor to override `OnSceneGUI()` to make clickable cubes to change the list of exits a room has. When I open the prefab for edition, the modifications need to be applied to the prefab asset but I can't seem to find how to do it.

This is in prefab Mode (since Unity 2018) when opening a prefab. I've tried using methods from `PrefabUtility` class, but the `GameObject` returned from `((RoomInfo)target).gameObject` does not belong to a prefab of any sort (?!?) see function `IsPartOfAnyPrefab(Object componentOrGameObject)`. Also, the problem is just saving the prefab asset since when editing a prefab instance in GameScene it works.

The class to inspect:

```
public class RoomInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, Range(1, 10)]
    private int XTile = 1;

    [SerializeField, Range(1, 7)]
    private int YTile = 1;

    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    private List<Vector2Int> Exits_Up = new List<Vector2Int>();

    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    private List<Vector2Int> Exits_Down = new List<Vector2Int>();

    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    private List<Vector2Int> Exits_Right = new List<Vector2Int>();

    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    private List<Vector2Int> Exits_Left = new List<Vector2Int>();
}
```

The Editor:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(RoomInfo), true)]
public class RoomInspector : Editor
{
    private RoomInfo room = null;

    private SerializedProperty upExitsProperty;
    private SerializedProperty downExitsProperty;
    private SerializedProperty rightExitsProperty;
    private SerializedProperty leftExitsProperty;

    private void Awake()
    {
        room = target as RoomInfo;

        upExitsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("Exits_Up");
        downExitsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("Exits_Down");
        rightExitsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("Exits_Right");
        leftExitsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("Exits_Left");
    }

    public void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        for (int i = 0; i < room.XTileNb; i++) // Down
        {
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(i + 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
            Vector2Int coordinates = new Vector2Int(i, 0);

            int index = -1;
            bool contain = Contains(downExitsProperty, coordinates, ref index);

            if (contain)
                Handles.color = new Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.8f);
            else
                Handles.color = new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.8f);

            if (Handles.Button(pos, Quaternion.identity, 1.0f, 1.0f, Handles.CubeHandleCap))
            {
                if (contain)
                    Remove(downExitsProperty, index);
                else
                    Add(downExitsProperty, coordinates);

                Repaint();
            }
        }

        // ...
        // Repeated 3 times for up, left and right of the room

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedPropertiesWithoutUndo();
    }
```

The methods `Contains`, `Remove` and `Add` are just help functions to manipulate the serialized properties as a list.

I'd like to be able to apply the changes to the prefab assets as it is made so designers can create a room prefab, it's not intended to be changed in game Scene. Thanks for any help ! :)

Comment: I fixed it, I will post an answer when I can see exactly what solve the problem.
I overrode `OnIspectorGUI()` with NO calls to `base.OnInspectorGUI()`. I change method `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedPropertiesWithoutUndo()` to `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()` don't think that's the problem

Comment: Did you sort this out finally? Am struggling with a similar thing, have a script to automate some work on prefabs, but have InstantiatePrefab failing .. tried ApplyModifiedProperties too but didn't get it to work yet